# Why won't the attribute of an input field in javascript change after onchange?

Tags: javascript, onchange

I tried looking around for an answer on here but couldn't find anything that resembles this problem, but what I am trying to do is get an input cell to format itself after a user inputs a number i.e. "100" will format to "100%" but that never happens.

When the onchange event fires it works and processes the input just fine but when it comes time to change the attribute "value" of the input field nothing happens. Why is this?

In my javascript I have

```
<input onchange='update();' ....
```

The update method is called but when it comes to this line

```
element.setAttribute(attr, value);
```

Nothing seems to happen. Does the focus of the input box need to be removed before changing the value of the input box?

Comment: So you want an input field [  100 ] to convert to [  100% ] ? use element.value = element.value + '%'

Answer (score 1):

Just call `.value`

```
element.value = value;
```

Comment: Yeah, no reason to be using setAttribute here

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know you could do that. I am using an IDE that shows methods or variables as you type and only setAttribute shows up, not .value
Thanks again though, I feel silly now. :/

Comment: @Cian -- No worries - if the IDE isn't specifically designed for JavaScript hint detection then assume there's always more methods available

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<input onchange='update(this);'
```

and

```
function update(element) {
element.value=value;
```

You don't seem to be telling it which element is being referred to (unless you call it elsewhere in your function).